# Drop bits by shifting left and right in Java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Is it possible to "drop" a couple of most significant bits of a byte number by executing shifting operations in Java?

The idea looks like this:

```
1010 1111 -> (<<2) -> 1011 1100 -> (>>2) -> 0010 1111 => 2 bits were dropped.
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you bitwise-and?

Comment: Should be easy enough to code up as a small example program. What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing that you're missing from your suggestion is that the right shift should use the *unsigned* right shift operator, `>>>`:

```
int result = (input << n) >>> n;
```